# How to force page validation on Page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a situation where i need the validators to fire on a page when it is loaded. But when i run Page.Validate(); the validators are not fired. I here this is because you cant do validation this early. Is there away around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use Validate when page is loaded, it needs a postback. You can try to validate from javascript. Take a look at this [Force Page Validation from Javascript](http://johnbierman.net/2008/12/16/force-page-validation-from-javascript.aspx)

Comment: this is for client side validation, what about server side validation? Still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the said method (Page.Validate) in Page_Load your validators will validate, if they exist in the control collection at this point.  Are you dealing with dynamic controls.  This may require a slightly different approach.